# Boat Spawn (Roblox Studio)

Tags: roblox

I'm trying(I'm very new) to make a game where you have to attack each other with a boat. There is a button on each island and when you press it, a boat should appear. (this works so far)
But as soon as you want to spawn a new boat it removes everyones boat. I thought it makes sense to use player.id but this still won't work. Does anyone know the solution?

Below you will find the code thats hidden in a part.

Thanks!

CODE:

```
local cd = script.Parent.ClickDetector
local boat = script.Parent.Parent.Firstboat
local button = script.Parent
local debounce = false



game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    print(player.UserId)
    local plruserid = player.UserId
    print(player.Name)


    boat.Parent = game.ServerStorage

cd.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(function()

    button.Transparency = 0.5
end)

cd.MouseHoverLeave:Connect(function()
    button.Transparency = 0
end)

    cd.MouseClick:Connect(function()
        local SetNameToBoat = plruserid
        print (SetNameToBoat)
        local oldboat = workspace:FindFirstChild(SetNameToBoat)


    if not debounce then
            if oldboat then
                oldboat : destroy()
        end
        debounce = true
        local NewBoat = boat:clone()
        NewBoat.Name = (SetNameToBoat)
        NewBoat.Parent = game.Workspace
        wait(5)
        debounce = false
        end
        
end)
end)
```

Comment: plruserid is a variable inside event method, which makes a variable not initialized for whole script. Place `local plruserid = null` at the top of the script, there where you hold `local boat`, after that replace the current local variable(`local plruserid = player.UserId`) to `plruserid = player.UserId`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I add (local plruserid = null) at the top of the script it gives a red line below the text? (no error or anything just a red line) Or does this not matter? It seems he doesn't know null..

Comment: @micegan This doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the code and found the solution:

```
local cd = workspace.Button:WaitForChild('ClickDetector')
local boat = game:GetService('ServerStorage'):WaitForChild('Boat')
local button = workspace:WaitForChild('Button')
local debounce = false

cd.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(function()

    button.Transparency = 0.5
end)

cd.MouseHoverLeave:Connect(function()
    button.Transparency = 0
end)

cd.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    local plruserid = player.UserId
    local SetNameToBoat = plruserid
    print(SetNameToBoat)
    local oldboat = workspace:FindFirstChild(SetNameToBoat)

    if not debounce then
        if oldboat then
            oldboat:destroy()
        end
        debounce = true
        local NewBoat = boat:clone()
        NewBoat.Name = SetNameToBoat
        NewBoat.Parent = game.Workspace
        wait(5)
        debounce = false
    end

end)
```

Comment: You are welcome!. Could you please mark my answer as correct so people know the question is solved?